# Access Combobox is replacing empty string with null, then throwing error 3162

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, combobox

I have an Access form bound to linked view called `vwBudgetEntries` from SQL Server. The form contains a combo box bound to a field called `SubcodeID` which is short text and has the following properties:

[image]

Meanwhile, the row source of the combo box pulls a unique list of all subcode id's, including one where it's an empty string. For some reason, however, selecting this option throws the following error:

[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out why. The value should be empty string, not null. If I change the combo box to a textbox and enter `""`, the update is accepted without any errors.

I've done what research I can and, so far, I've only found 2 workarounds:

1. Change the field properties to allow null, then replace null values with an empty string after the control updates.
2. Trap the error in the form_error event, undo the update and supply the value using VBA.

Neither workaround is ideal. Can someone explain why this error is occurring in the first place and what I might do to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a NULL value? What does the resultset from your view look like?

Comment: Why allow empty string or null in this field?

Comment: @critical_error when I add `WHERE SubcodeID=''` to the combo box row source, it returns 1 record. Whereas when I add `WHERE SubcodeID Is Null`, it returns 0 records. That's why I'm so confused that the error message suggests I tried to assign a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Storing empty strings should be avoided for anything else than very special cases, or you will meet issues like this. So:

- Set *Required* to *No*
- Set *Allow Zero Length* to *No*
- Store *Null* for the choice of unknown value for `SubcodeID`

Comment: unfortunately, the backend database uses empty strings, and I don't have the ability to change it.